# Can't establish connection to DB2

Tags: php, linux, db2

I am using Linux Suse 13.1. I have compiled the ibm_db2 extension for PHP successfully but when I run the connection test script it returns connection failed. I do not know where I am going wrong. Are there some other steps I need to do after installing the PHP extensions? Please note that I am using Data Client Server 9.7.

This is my script.

```
<?php


$database = 'Database_name';
$user = 'myusername';
$password = 'passwrd';
$hostname = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx';
$port = db_port;


$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
```

Comment: Can you establish the connection _outside_ PHP, e.g. with the DB2 command line processor?

Comment: I connect to this DB with AQUA Data Studio. I just want to automate some report so that I do not always have to do stuff manually with AQUA. And oh, its a remote DB.

Comment: Aqua uses the JDBC driver, if I'm not mistaken, so it doesn't mean much for diagnostics of the CLI driver.

Comment: Okay this provides some enlightenment...but I am still stuck. Tried on windows via browser and on linux but it is not working.